# How to access DataGridView in an event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a `TabControl` which contains a `DataGridView` and a `ToolStripButton`.
The `DataGridView` has multiple select enabled. The function of the toolStripButton is to delete rows from the `DataGridView`.

The DataGridView has a BindingSource:

```
partial class MyView 
{
    ...
    this.myBindingSource  = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
    ...
    this.dataGridView.DataSource = this.myBindingSource;
    this.dataGridView.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    this.dataGridView.MultiSelect = true;
    ....
    this.tsbDelete.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tsbDelete_Click);
    ...
```

I have an event handler for the delete button like so:

```
public partial class MyView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl, IMyView
    {
    ...
    private void tsbDelete_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        var current = myBindingSource.Current;
        ...
    }
```

**current** is a single selection. If multiple rows have been selected, it is the last selected. I can't figure out how to get all rows selected. The difficulty is that the `DataGridView` is not available in the event handler (or I don't know how to access it and that is the problem). If I could, I could access [DataGridView.SelectedRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=VS.100).aspx).  The **sender** is the button, which is not directly connected to the DataGridView.
How do I do this?

Fully specified:

> System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
>       System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
>           System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource
>       System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton

Comment: You may not be able to access the DGV because your handler is public and your constructor class is not?  I've always been able to access elements from within handlers with no issue.

Comment: Heh, I've done stupider things so don't feel too bad. I've added my response as an answer. Please mark as the answer.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to access the DGV because your handler is public and your constructor class is not? I've always been able to access elements from within handlers with no issue.